# How to exclude certain files from the plugin editor?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, dashboard

Is there a way to tell WordPress not to list certain files of my plugin in the Plugins -> Editor screen?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the plugin editor is. I have an Appearance -> Editor, but no Plugins -> Editor.

Comment: There is a Plugins -> Editor on 3.9-alpha, at least. I can't check other recent releases right now.

Comment: I think it's been there for a very long time I always use it to fix certain problems in PHP for customers when I don't have FTP access just wp-admin. But it shows files that shouldn't be edited, ever - it's just clutter to list there.

Appearance -> Editor is the theme editor by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out, there is just one filter hook in the `wp-admin/plugin-editor.php` that can be useful but it's enough (otherwise one would probably need to mess with the output buffer).

```
if(is_admin()){
    add_filter('editable_extensions', array($this, 'my_editable_extensions'));
}
```

and then

```
function my_editable_extensions($editable_extensions){
    if(empty($_POST['plugin']) || (!empty($_POST['plugin']) && $_POST['plugin'] !== "plugin-name/plugin-name.php"){
        return $editable_extensions;
    }else{
        return array_diff($editable_extensions, array('txt', 'html'));
    }
}
```

Note: `wp_reset_vars()` is called so the only way to know which plugin's files are being edited is from the `$_POST`.